# My reindexing is not working

Tags: magento2.3, indexing

I am stuck for two days because my reindexing does not work by, I tried several things that I found on the net but nothing helps it does not work.

this is what I tried to do:

```
php bin / magento indexer: reset
```

then

```
php bin / magento indexer: reindex
```

which gave me as result this:

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log.
Table "natu_catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_replica" does not exist
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:06
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log.
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Google Product Removal Feed index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Google Product Feed index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
```

****But when I do php bin / magento indexer: status:**
**I still have 3 indexes which are still reindex required****

```
+ ----------------------------- + ------------------ + ----------- + ----------------- + ------------------ +
| Title | Status | Update On | Schedule Status | Schedule Updated |
+ ----------------------------- + ------------------ + ----------- + ----------------- + ------------------ +
| Catalog Product Rule | Reindex required | Save | | |
| Catalog Rule Product | Reindex required | Save | | |
| Catalog Search | Ready | Save | | |
| Category Products | Ready | Save | | |
| Customer Grid | Ready | Save | | |
| Design Config Grid | Ready | Save | | |
| Google Product Feed | Ready | Save | | |
| Google Product Removal Feed | Ready | Save | | |
| Inventory | Ready | Save | | |
| Product Categories | Ready | Save | | |
| Product EAV | Reindex required | Save | | |
| Product Price | Ready | Save | | |
| Stock | Ready | Save | | |
+ ----------------------------- + ------------------ + ----------- + ----------------- + ------------------ +
```

What to do ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: you can found the error in the exception log file.

Comment: there is nothing in the logs

Comment: The errors are right there in the CLI response. One says that the table natu_catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_replica does not exist so you'll need to fix that. The other two say see the exception log. Do you really get nothing when you tail var/log/exception.log ? I'd be surprised if there was nothing in there about these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I changed permissions from Super User to Group User. What worked for me was:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile (if in production)
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush

Hope this helps.